# Composer install log location on Ubuntu

Tags: composer-php, ubuntu-16.04, drupal-8

I am trying to `install` Drupal's OpenEdu project on Ubuntu 16.04 with composer by running the following command:

```
composer create-project imagex/openedu-project openedu
```

This produces a load of messages pertaining to PHP settings, and the project is not installed. The problem is that I cannot see all the messages on the screen (VMware console), only the last x lines.
The question is: where can I see the full result of the attempt at creation of the project?

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect composer output to file:

```
composer create-project imagex/openedu-project openedu --no-interaction --no-progress > install.log 2>&1
```

And then use `less` to browse the file:

```
less install.log
```

Comment: Thanks, evenutally I came up with the idea to use the console in Webmin, but the above comes in handy too.